# Does PL/JSON software support UTF-8 characters

Tags: json, plsql, pljson

I'm using PL/JSON to parse data from MongoDB to Oracle DB. The Packages work fine with latin characters. However, whenver there is json_value with chinese characters, the resulted value in oracle is totally corrupted (question marks, symbole ... etc).
As an example, I use the following line to parse:

```
Remarks := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'Remarks');
```

I'm aware the type json and get_string function are using varchar and not nvarchar. More importantly, Oracle DB instance supports chinese (I can see when I insert directly into table, no corruption occurs. Only when I parse chinese json file it gets corrupted.)
So my question is, Does PL/JSON software support chinesecharacters? Do I need to update the package on my own to accommodate chinese characters? Where exactly needs to be fixed?

In adidtion, I ran the following:

```
select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

and it returns : AL32UTF8.

does not mean my DB is configured for UTF-8? or there are other things need to be checked for this pupose?

**Update**

Inspired by @jsumners' comment, I tried to track the corruption source and I found it from the beginning. That is, the snippet below is run before using PL/SJON to receive the htp response:

```
BEGIN
      LOOP
        UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_http_response, buf);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(buf);
        l_response_text := l_response_text || buf;
      END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body THEN
      NULL;
    END;
```

The line `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(buf);` returns corrupted fields of json. I'm not sure if this is related to the way I send and receive htp requests. Noteworthy, buf is nvarchar2.

Comment: Does the corruption happen when you use the `.print()` method to print your JSON data to `dbms_output`?

Comment: In fact, it's corrupted from the beginning. Please see me updated question

Comment: My next suggestion would be to read the data into a BLOB as raw data with `utl_http.read_raw`. Then write the contents of that BLOB to a text file using `utl_file`. At that point, you should be able to determine where the corruption is occurring.

Comment: It was solved by adding `utl_http.set_body_charset(l_http_request, 'UTF-8');`. Then, there was no issue with PL/JSON supporting UTF-8 :)

Comment: Post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Maybe you also want to have a look at https://github.com/doberkofler/PLSQL-JSON