# ORACLE: How to parse json UTF8

Tags: json, oracle, utf-8, encode

When parsing json, the special characters do not consider, how do I solve it?

```
declare 
  str       varchar2(4000) := '[{"id":"1","PRM_CODID":"R","PRM_TIPID":"REGISTRO UNICO CONTRIBUYENTE"},{"id":"2","PRM_CODID":"C","PRM_TIPID":"**CÉDULA DE IÑENTIDAD**"},{"id":"3","PRM_CODID":"P","PRM_TIPID":"PASAPORTE"}]';
  l_obj  json_list;
  l_results       json_list;
  l_tempobj       json;
   l_addr_comps    json_list;
   l_addr          json;
   ls varchar2(100);


begin
        l_obj := json_list(str);

        FOR i IN 1 .. l_obj.count
        LOOP
             l_addr := json(l_obj.get(i));
             ls := JSON_EXT.PP(l_addr, 'PRM_TIPID') ;
             Dbms_output.put_line(ls);
        END LOOP;
end;
/
```

> **Result**:
>   "REGISTRO UNICO CONTRIBUYENTE"
>   "**C\u00C9**DULA DE I\u00D1ENTIDAD"
>   "PASAPORTE"
>   PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: Related: [Does PL/JSON software support UTF-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370260/does-pl-json-software-support-utf-8-characters) , and perhaps also [Difference between VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) and NVARCHAR2(10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508351/difference-between-varchar210-char-and-nvarchar210)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding Oracle provides PL/SQL DOM APIs for JSON handling.You can check the below link for more details.

[Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml25.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNISTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions204.htm) function:

```
select unistr( replace('C\u00C9DULA DE I\u00D1ENTIDAD', '\u', '\') ) as x
from dual;

X                  
-------------------
CÉDULA DE IÑENTIDAD
```